# Can't get email address or apple id using Sign in with Apple REST API

Tags: javascript, php, api, applet

I'm trying to implement Sign with Apple ID to my website.

I can get **code and id_token** using [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple) after that I can get **access_token, token_type, expires_in, refresh_token, id_token** from https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token but I still didn't figure out how can I get client's email address and apple id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part of the response is the `id_token`. This token is a JSON Web Token (JWT). 
You can decode this JWT and you will get the user's email address in addition to some other values.

However you won't get the user's apple id. On top, you won't get the user's real email address as far as I can tell.

You can get more info about the sign in flow on Apple's developer documentation:  [Authenticating Users with Sign in with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple)

Comment: Thank you so much, I decoded id_token which is come from https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token and I can see client's email.

Comment: But, when I decoded my idToken, I'm not getting email and user infoamtion, however I have already added name and email in scopes.